# Android Studio - Show only one part of website on webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, web

I want to show a specific part of a website on Webview.

[image]

As you can see `tabbertab` class which I want to use on my activity. I've tried the code below, but it did not work. How can I do that?

```
vv.loadUrl("https://mia.gov.az/?/az/driverlicense/");
    vv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            vv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByClassName('tabbertab')");

        }

    });
```